# Deleting indexes in List based on specific values

Tags: python, list

I am trying to solve the following:

*Return the sum of the numbers in the array, returning 0 for an empty array. Except the number 13 is very unlucky, so it does not count and numbers that come immediately after a 13 also do not count.*

Here is what I have, the idea here being the 13 and 1(right after it) get deleted and then the remaining numbers are summed.  The issue I have is the delete portion, it's not actually deleting anything.  Is this a syntax issue?

```
x = [1,2,2,1,13,1]

def sum13(nums):
    for i in nums:
        if i == 13:
            del nums[i:i+1]
    return sum(nums)

print(sum13(x))

20 <-- should be 6
```

Comment: You really shouldn't be deleting from a list while iterating it. Rebuild a new list.

Comment: Remember that slices in python are non-inclusive, so `nums[4]` and `nums[4:5]` will both only return `13` and `[13]` respectively

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is with your index. `i` is the number in the list, not the index.
Here's a way to solve your problem:

```
x = [1,2,2,1,13,1]

def sum13(nums):
    for i, num in enumerate(nums):
        if num == 13:
            del nums[i:i+2] # This removes the index i and the index i+1
    return sum(nums)

print(sum13(x))
>>> 6
```

EDIT:
As Thierry Lathuille mentioned in the comments, this doesn't adequately account for the case where you have repeated '13's. Assuming you want this behavior, here's a way you can do that:

```
def sum13(nums):
    for i, num in enumerate(nums):
        if num == 13:
            stop_cut = i + 1     
            while nums[stop_cut] == 13:
                stop_cut += 1
            del nums[i:stop_cut+1]
    return sum(nums)
```

Comment: With `x = [13, 13, 1]`, you get 1, while you should get 0 as 1 after a 13 should not count.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille It's actually not clear from the instructions whether that second 13 *counts*.

Comment: I added a way to deal with repeated 13s. Thanks for pointing that out @ThierryLathuille

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are looping through the list, just keep a running sum and a record of the previous value. If `i` is not `13` and the previous was not `13` add to the sum No need to modify the list passed in.

```
def sum13(nums):
    sum = 0
    last = None
    for i in nums:
        if i != 13 and last != 13:
             sum += i
        last = i
    return sum
```

Comment: Author said to don't count numbers that *come immediately after a 13* not all of which are after 13.

Comment: Thanks @FilipMłynarski misunderstood that line.

Answer (score 1):

Here's example with recurrent function. As longest as there's `13` in list we sum everything that's before it and `sum13` everything that's after that `13`.

```
x = [1,2,2,1,13,1]

def sum13(nums, first_call=False):
    if not first_call and nums[0] != 13:
        nums = nums[1:]
    if 13 in nums:
        return sum(nums[:nums.index(13)]) + sum13(nums[nums.index(13)+1:])
    return sum(nums)

print(sum13(x, True)) # -> 6
```

Note that this solution works with neighboring `13`s.

```
x = [13, 13, 1]
print(sum13(x, True)) # -> 0
```

Answer (score 1):

One issue is that you are using your list element value as your index. Here's a solution using a generator. First identify index of values to ignore, then create a new list excluding those values.

```
x = [1,2,2,1,13,1]

def sum13(nums):

    def filter13(nums):
        for n, i in enumerate(nums):
             if i == 13:
                  yield n
                  yield n + 1

    bad_ix = set(filter13(nums))
    new_nums = [x for n, x in enumerate(nums) if n not in bad_ix]
    return sum(new_nums)

sum13(x)
```